# Shooting Multiple Bullets in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a simple variation of space invaders using pygame. Here is some working code:

```
import pygame, random, time, tkinter
pygame.init()

def main():
    X = 672
    Y = 500

win = pygame.display.set_mode((X,Y))
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Invaders')



class player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.lives = 3
        self.vel = 5
        self.points = 0
        self.explosionYN = False
        self.explosionCount = 0
        self.highScore = int(text)
    def explosion(self, win):
        if self.explosionYN:
            win.blit(explosion[self.explosionCount], (self.x-20, self.y-30, 100, 100))
            self.explosionCount += 1
        if not self.explosionYN:
            self.explosionCount = 0
        if self.explosionCount + 1 > 6:
            self.explosionYN = False
            self.explosionCount = 0
    def move(self, win):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and self.x > -1:
            self.x -= self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and self.x < 623:
            self.x += self.vel
        if keys[pygame.K_q]:
            if self.x >= 623:
                self.x = 0
            if self.x < 0:
                self.x = 623

class invader(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 1
    def reset(self, win):
        self.y = 0
        self.x = random.randint(5, (X-35))

class bullet(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 0
    def shoot(self, win):
        laser.play(0)
        self.x = ship.x + 22
        self.y = ship.y
        self.vel = 15
    def reset(self, win):
        self.vel = 0
        self.y = 510


ship = player(X//2 - (0.5*52), 435, 52, 52)
alien = invader(random.randint(0,707),0,31,25)
bullet = bullet(750, 510, 5, 7)



while run:
    pygame.time.delay(25)

    alien.y += alien.vel
    bullet.y -= bullet.vel

    if alien.y > 500:
        ship.explosionYN = True
        ship.explosion(win)
        loseLife.play(0)
        if ship.explosionCount+ 1 >= 6:
            win.fill((0,0,0))
            pause()
            ship.lives -= 1
            alien.reset(win)
        elif ship.lives <= 1:
            test()

    if bullet.y <= 0:
        bullet.reset(win)

    alien1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,0), (alien.x,alien.y,31,25))
    bullet1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,100,255), (bullet.x, bullet.y, bullet.width, bullet.height))

    if pygame.Rect.colliderect(alien1, bullet1):
        ship.points += 1
        if ship.highScore < ship.points:
            ship.highScore += 1
        bullet.reset(win)
        kill.play(0)
        alien.y = 0
        alien.reset(win)
        alien.vel += 0.5
        ship.vel += 0.25

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    ship.move(win)
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bullet.shoot(win)
    if keys[pygame.K_p]:
        pause()

    drawGame()

main()
```

*I have omitted some code that I don't think is relevant*

The problem is that only one bullet can be displayed on screen at a time.
So I tried this instead.

```
 if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bullet1 = pygame.draw.rect(win, (#stuff))
        bullet.shoot(win)
```

But now the bullet doesn't show at all.
Literally nothing happens.
I have looked at some other posts but as I am new to pygame I can't make head or tail of them.([Multiple Bullets pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175956/multiple-bullets-pygame))

What is an easy and effiecient way to be able show multiple bullets on pygame?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way that this is done is by creating a list of bullets.

```
bullets = []
```

Then when you fire a bullet you add it to the list

```
bullets.append(Bullet(750, 510, 5, 7))
```

And inside your while loop, you will update and redraw each bullet in turn using a for loop to iterate over each bullet

```
for bullet in bullets:
    bullet.y -= bullet.vel # Move Bullet
    # Draw bullet
    # Check for collision with player/enemy
```

This obviously isn't a complete code listing but hopefully it is enough to get you started.

You'll also end up having to create a list of enemies too if you want to create a space invaders clone.

You may find the recently released book "Code the Classics" from the Raspberry Pi Foundation helpful as it explains how to create some classic games using Pygame. It's a free download (or you can buy the hardcopy)

Edit: Consider following the Python style guide PEP-8 and renaming your classes to be title case. For example

```
class bullet():
```

should be

```
class Bullet():
```

This will help with any confusion between the variable `bullet` and the class of the same name.

Comment: I have tried this but when i press space it gives me an error message: line 218, in main
    bullets.append(bullet(750, 510, 5, 7))
TypeError: 'bullet' object is not callable

Comment: I'd suggest following the PEP-8 guidelines and renaming your `bullet` class to `Bullet`. This way you won't mix up the variable `bullet` and the class `bullet`. I'll update my answer.